# How to get closest div html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple ul and li's and want to get the closest div respective html content when click on li.

I have tried this like `$(this).closest('div').find('.email-con').show().html()` getting undefined.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3 subs-alrts">
        <ul class="cp-expand sent-mails" id="sent-mails">
            <li class="clearfix">
                <div class="cp-exp-title clearfix col-md-12">Dasara Mail</div>
                <div class="cp-exp-con col-md-12">
                   <ul> 
                        <li class="evnt-mail-cls" >06/01/16</li>
                   </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 email-con" id="email-con" style="display:none">
    dasara mail content
    </div>
</div>
```

My script is:

```
$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function(){
        alert($(this).closest('div').find('.email-con').show().html());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to find the content of `.email-con` then you need to traverse upto `.subs-alrts` and then pick its next element.

```
$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function(){
        alert($(this).closest('.subs-alrts').next('.email-con').show().html());
});
```

See the final code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).closest('.subs-alrts').next('.email-con');
    x.show();
    alert(x.html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-3 subs-alrts">
    <ul class="cp-expand sent-mails" id="sent-mails">
      <li class="clearfix">
        <div class="cp-exp-title clearfix col-md-12">Dasara Mail</div>
        <div class="cp-exp-con col-md-12">
          <ul>
            <li class="evnt-mail-cls">06/01/16</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 email-con" id="email-con" style="display:none">
    dasara mail content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: email-con is a class, too

Comment: @user3154108 yeah just noticed. See the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('ul li').click(function(){

  var a=$(this).closest('div');
  a=$(this).closest('div').text();
  alert(a);

});
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You need :

```
$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function(){
    alert($(this).closest('div').parent().find('.email-con').show().html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function(){
    alert($(this).parents('.subs-alrts').parent().find('.email-con').show().html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function(){
    alert($('.email-con').show().html());
});
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Change for jquery code with following , it may help you.

```
$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function(){
    alert($(this).parents('.subs-alrts').parent('div').find('.email-con').show().html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two way of doing this explained in code comments :

**Note**: the second (and easiest) require that you add a class to your top div (because col-md-12 is a bootstrap one that could change in the future)

```js
// if you click there will be 2 alerts because I wrote two way of doing it :

$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function() {
    var html = $(this)
        // Get the parent with class "subs-alrts"
        .parents(".subs-alrts")
        // get the following element that have the class "email-con"
        .next('.email-con')
        .show().html();
    alert(html);
});


// OR


$('#sent-mails .cp-exp-con ul li').click( function() {
    var html = $(this)
        // Get the parent with class "MAIN_DIV"
        .parents(".MAIN_DIV")
        // find the child element that have the class "email-con"
        .find('.email-con')
        .show().html();
    alert(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 MAIN_DIV">
    <div class="col-md-3 subs-alrts">
        <ul class="cp-expand sent-mails" id="sent-mails">
            <li class="clearfix">
                <div class="cp-exp-title clearfix col-md-12">Dasara Mail</div>
                <div class="cp-exp-con col-md-12">
                   <ul> 
                        <li class="evnt-mail-cls" >06/01/16</li>
                   </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 email-con" id="email-con" style="display:none">
    dasara mail content
    </div>
</div>
```